# ¿Cómo aplico text-align:center en Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

he probado con lo siguiente:

```
text-align: -webkit-center;
```

Pero el texto sigue sin centrarse en el navegador móvil Safari. No me interpreta, como el resto de navegadores que el text-align:center ¿Cómo puedo centrar un texto en css y html en Safari?

Comment: que version de safari usas?

Comment: Uso la más actualizada del iPhone; ni idea de cuál es.

Comment: podrias publicar el codigo html que intentas centrar?

Comment: <div class="uno" style="text-align_center;"><a href="www.test.com">Texto centrado</div>

Simplemente es algo así. Luego muevo los estilos creando una clase para ese div, pero no se centra en Safari. De hecho he permutado text-align:center por text-align: -webkit-center; y no centra en ningún navegador

Answer (score 0):

Modifique el codigo que escribiste en los comentarios y centre el texto haciendo uso de flex. Quizas flex o `text-indent: porcentaje` sea la unica alternativa ya que parece haber un bug en safari que data del 2010 con respecto al uso de text-align.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40216

```css
.uno {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width:1000px;
  background:lightblue
}
```

```html
<div class="uno">
  <a href="www.test.com">Texto centrado</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder. He añadido el flex y el justify.content y nada, sigue sin funcionar en el Safari. ¿Alguna alternativa? Muchas gracias por la ayuda